# Check if current user (session) is fan of my page or not

Tags: facebook

I need using javascript to check if the current user is fan of my page.

I goto here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/pages.isFan/. In Test Console I don't understand about Application parameter?

I using this code below, but it's always alert "You like the Application" for any user even guest

```
window.checkDoesLike = function() {
  FB.api({ method: 'pages.isFan', page_id: '138992766181857' }, function(resp) {
    if (resp) {
      alert('You like the Application.');
    } else {
      alert("You don't like the Application.");
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: for any request you made through API, there should be a response, that's why its always alert 'you like the application'. just alert (resp) and then code based on the response data.

Comment: In document "Response returns 1 or 0" ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written an extended tutorial about this [here](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/facebook-api-check-if-a-user-is-fan-of-a-facebook-page/20/#using_the_rest_api).

There are a couple of points to highlight:

1. You are missing the `uid` parameter
2. using `if(resp)` is not enough

Better code:

```
FB.api({ method: 'pages.isFan', page_id: 'page_id_here', uid: 'user_id_here' }, function(resp) {
    if (resp == true) {
      alert('user_id likes the Application.');
    } else if(resp.error_code) {
      alert(resp.error_msg);
    } else {
      alert("user_id doesn't like the Application.");
    }
});
```

Quoting:

> Once again, you need to check the response of the call if true or
>   not…using if(resp) is NOT enough! The example in the [Facebook
>   JavaScript Test Console](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/console) is a bit misleading (the does-like example),
>   since if you don’t grant the user_likes permission and just try it
>   with uid: '579187141' it would result that the user likes the
>   application which is not true!
>   *P.S: I just decremented my user id to get the above user which (it
>   seems) he has a strict privacy for pages he likes!*

Comment: How I get user id of current visitor? I want to check current visitors which they already logged in facebook, not a specific user.

Comment: @StoneHeart: well, if you don't pass the user id it should take it from the session by default. Try using the code i've posted above without `uid` if it didn't work make sure you are asking for the `user_likes` permission.

Comment: How to grant permissions to allow access to likes?

Comment: @StoneHeart: Well, you can ask for the permission with this function [FB.login](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/)

Comment: @ifaour why it is important to add the app ID and secret. what if I want to check a fanpage which is not associated with the app I own? moreover, fanpage is not associated with any app at all, am I right?

Comment: @IvorySantos, what do you mean by *check a page*?